# will a program deadlock if the error stream is not read from regularly?

Tags: c#, stderr

I originally wanted to quickly check an error stream from a program right after it starts to make sure that it ran successfully.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
string errortext = Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

However, I was wondering do I have to redirect the Process's standard error back to a file.

I would think that if nothing is reading from std error and the program writes many errors to the stream, then eventually the buffer will fill up. I don't know exactly how `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError` works, but I assume that the buffer won't automatically write to a file when full.

In order to avoid freezing up the program I'm reading from, should stderror be redirected to a file instead? and then just read that file into the string to check for errors at startup?

Comment: The [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx) should answer your question.

Comment: Please be more specific about what it is in the documentation you are having trouble understanding. The docs are **very clear** regarding the deadlock risk that exists when redirecting both stdout and stderr. If you have a _specific_ question relative to what the documentation says, please edit your question so that it's clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".